# Why does multiple access tokens work in Keycloak?

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I'm checking out Keycloak and attempting to secure a REST service written in Springboot. I found a sample at Github and it worked. Question is once I obtain a new access token via refresh token, I still could use the old access token.

I configured the Springboot adapter for Keycloak and I tried setting the access token life to two minutes in Keycloak via web portal for the relevant client.

Is this behavior normal? any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

In case of keycloak, it does not invalidate the previously issued access token. You can validate this by viewing the sessions tab:

[image]

In my case, I logged in with administrator_user from 2 different browsers and in turn I received 2 access_tokens, both of which were valid.

[image]

Since access token is a JWT , which is self contained, and has an expiry time field. It remains valid till the expiry time is reached.

**One use case I can see behind this is when you want to use same user account on multiple devices. E.g. think of gmail (not that it uses keycloak but a generic example). When you login to the desktop gmail site, you don't want to be logged out of your mobile gmail app.**

Comment: Thanks tryingToLearn, since you put it that way it makes sense. I'll try to dig in more on this.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is perfectly normal.

Access tokens lasts till the expiration time which is set in the token.
Access tokens are short lived and refresh tokens lives longer.

It does not matter - You can generate as many access tokens you want through the refresh token. All the tokens will work till their ttl is reached.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas raghav, but the thing is I've seen behaviors in certain systems where once you acquire a new access token via refresh token the previous access token is invalidated. That is why I'm having a hard time believing this behavior. Do you have any references which supports this please do share. Thanks.

Comment: There is no mention of this in keycloak documentation. So, generally access tokens are short lived, say - 1min or 2 min and the refresh token can reissue the new access token as soon as the first one gets expired. So even if keycloak is not expiring the earlier AT, it is bound to get expired shortly. It is the action token in keycloak in keycloak that gets expired once the new action token is created for the same subject. Examples of action tokens are Password rest token etc. SInce keycloak store these tokens in its DB but this is not the use case with AT. Hope this explanation helps.

Comment: Thanks again raghav, will do some digging.